# Unittest a route that returns a json gives this error: "TypeError: decoding str is not supported"

Tags: python, flask, python-unittest

I have a route that returns a json.
I am testing this route to check if the returned json equals my expected json.
When i test this route i get this error: decoding str is not supported

This function is working fine, it returns the list that i want.
Code from the function i want to test:

```
@app.route('/users', methods=['GET'])
@jwt_required
def user_list():



    users = ldap.get_group_members('ship_crew')
    user_list = []

    for user in users:
        user_list.append((str(user, encoding='utf-8').split(",")[0].split("=")[1]))
    return jsonify(user_list)
```

Test code:

```
@patch('dev_maintenance.user_list.ldap.get_group_members')
def test_content_type_json(get_group_members, access_token):

    get_group_members.return_value = ["cn=Philip J. Fry,ou=people,dc=planetexpress,dc=com",\
                                     "cn=Turanga Leela,ou=people,dc=planetexpress,dc=com",\
                                     "cn=Bender Bending Rodr\u00edguez,ou=people,dc=planetexpress,dc=com"]

    with app.test_client() as client:

        response = client.get('/users',
                              data=dict(user="hermes", passwd="hermes"),
                              headers={"Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(access_token)} )

    expected_json = ["Philip J. Fry", "Turanga Leela", "Bender Bending Rodr\u00edguez"]

    assert response.get_json() == expected_json
```

error:

```
 @app.route('/users', methods=['GET'])
    @jwt_required
    def user_list():



        users = ldap.get_group_members('ship_crew')
        user_list = []

        for user in users:
>           user_list.append((str(user, encoding='utf-8').split(",")[0].split("=")[1]))
E           TypeError: decoding str is not supported
```

Comment: any help? i'am really stuck in this

Answer (score 0):

so i fix the issue after a while.
The problem was that my data was bytes and i was passing strings in the test case.
so changed this

```
get_group_members.return_value =  [u"cn=Philip J. Fry,ou=people,dc=planetexpress,dc=com".encode('utf-8'),
                                      u"cn=Turanga Leela,ou=people,dc=planetexpress,dc=com".encode('utf-8'),
                                      u"cn=Bender Bending Rodr\u00edguez,ou=people,dc=planetexpress,dc=com".encode('utf-8')]
```